# how to split pair values in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a dict/json structure as follows

```
jdata = {"result": [{"(x1,y1)": "(66, 174)", "(x2,y2)": "(140, 365)"}], "det_no": 1, "exec_time": 0.09536290168762207}
for result in jdata["result"]:
    x1y1 = result["(x1,y1)"][0]
    print(x1y1)
```

the output get from execution of above code is just

```
(
```

I like to get two values as 66 and 174

Not well familiar with python.  Kindly help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply with *one-line* expression:

```
x1, y1 = jdata["result"][0]["(x1,y1)"][1:-1].split(', ')
print(x1, y1)   # 66 174
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `ast` module.

**Ex:**

```
import ast

jdata = {"result": [{"(x1,y1)": "(66, 174)", "(x2,y2)": "(140, 365)"}], "det_no": 1, "exec_time": 0.09536290168762207}
for result in jdata["result"]:
    x1, y1 = ast.literal_eval(result["(x1,y1)"])
    print(x1, y1)  # -->66 174
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

```
>>> from ast import literal_eval
>>> jdata = {"result": [{"(x1,y1)": "(66, 174)", "(x2,y2)": "(140, 365)"}], "det_no": 1, "exec_time": 0.09536290168762207}
>>> for result in jdata['result']:
    for key,val in result.items():
        tuple_data = literal_eval(val)
        print(f'{type(tuple_data)}: {tuple_data}')


<class 'tuple'>: (66, 174)
<class 'tuple'>: (140, 365)
```